# authenticate users from specific domain using google+ api

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, google-plus

I am trying to authenticate users for an internal app using the google+ api. I dont require any user details or profile data, I only need to authenticate my users from their correct hosted domain (hd). I am currently using the javascript quick-start from google developers and have narrowed the problem down to the data attributes that make up the object "authResult":

```
data-scope="openid" + "hd=example.com"
data-clientId="307521491002-2sducfmnk2kue3th4emtc5bu1t27nn9g.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-callback="onSignInCallback"
data-theme="light"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
```

Through combing the docs and finding similar issues on stack overflow, I understand that my main issue lies in the scope parameter "[hd=example.com](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/getOpenIdConnect#hd)" to allow only users coming from a specific domain to be authenticated, I just have not found the right way to do it. Thoughts?

**Many thanks!!**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VJV5/)

Answer (score 0):

What does correct hosted domain mean ?

From the docs :

> Use the hd parameter only for Google Apps hosted accounts

Comment: "hosted domain" (or hd) refers to accounts hosted by google...a prime example of this is a group or company that runs their email under their domain (ex: bigco.com) while still being a series of gmail accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this before, to be honest, and I haven't found a reference to including the hd parameter as part of the scope. (Do you have a reference for that? I'm curious.) But...

...the syntax for the `data-scope` parameter is clearly wrong. That isn't valid HTML markup. If the hd part is supposed to be part of the scope, it should probably be something more like

```
data-scope="openid hd=example.com"
```

Comment: yea I realized that as soon as I posted it...the scopes are denoted by spaces within the scope parameter...here are two links including the scope parameter "hd"...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/SRStIuewiws

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

I've currently decided to pursue this issue server-side for security purposes, and will be updating with my finds.